# PDO Statements aren't being submitted to database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm fairly new to using PDO, and I'm attempting to migrate some of my websites from mysql_* to it.

I have formed the following:

```
if ($userData) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE user_id = " . $db->quote($userData['id']);
    $result = $db->query($query);


    if ($result) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            if ($result->rowCount > 1) {
                $sql = "DELETE FROM tokens WHERE `user_id` = " . $db->quote($userData['id']) . "' AND `id` != '" . $row['id'];
                $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->execute();
            }
        }

        if (!$row) {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO  tokens SET `user_id` = " . $db->quote($userData['id']) . "', `name` = '" . $db->quote($userData['name']) . "',`access_token` = '" . $db->quote($token) . "',`alive` ='Y'";
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
        } else {
            $sql = "UPDATE tokens SET `access_token` = " . $db->quote($token) . "' WHERE `id` = " . $row['id'] . "";
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
    }
}
```

`$userData` is a Facebook API variable.

The snippet above looks fine to me, but when I run through it on a live website, the information isn't added to the database.

How would I fix this? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `DELETE * FROM` - get rid of the star. Plus, just for argument's sake, `table` is a MySQL reserved word ;-) You also need to check for errors/exceptions.

Comment: Add `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened.

Comment: Can i assume your table is not called "table"? Side note, you should really use prepared statements as intended instead of injecting the value into the query. You shouldn't ever have to use quote, instead you put ? or :name into your query and then use bind_param to safely set the value.

Comment: `table` is just the first word I came up with to replace the original tablename :-P
And no errors were thrown

Comment: Consult beginning of comment #1

Comment: That's the first thing I attempted.

Comment: If you got rid of the star, then please modify your question/code to reflect the change.

Comment: Another thing; there's nothing TO prepare because you're not using prepared statements http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements. Change all `$db->prepare($sql);` to `$db->query($sql);` - that's why it's failing *silently*.

Comment: Prepare doesn't require binding, the sql should be executing as is. `if (!$row)` will always be true due to the while above, not sure if that has anything to do with it. Print out $db->errorInfo() after each execute to see if it is generating a sql error. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php

Comment: I've made that change, but it still isn't adding the info to the DB

Comment: Then try adding error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: This is what I'm getting;
`Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => ) 
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Y'' at line 1' in /dashboard.php:38 Stack trace: #0 /dashboard.php(38): PDO->query('INSERT INTO to...') #1 {main} thrown in /dashboard.php on line 38`

Comment: That's why you should be using prepared statements. Now you have to fix the quotes in `$sql = "INSERT INTO  tokens...`

Comment: `" . $db->quote($userData['id']) . "'` you're probably missing a quote here. Try `'" . $db->quote($userData['id']) . "'` or remove one `" . $db->quote($userData['id']) . "`

Comment: I'll definitely use prepared statements in the future haha, still no luck with the quote

Comment: Attempted all of the above, still no rows :-(

Comment: Do you have data in there at least? and did you fix the error? `the right syntax to use near 'Y'' at line 1`

Comment: Well, good luck with that. I wish you well.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a single quote

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO  tokens SET `user_id` = <<HERE>>" . $db->quote($userData['id']) . "', `name` = '" . $db->quote($userData['name']) . "',`access_token` = '" . $db->quote($token) . "',`alive` ='Y'";
```

should be:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO  tokens SET `user_id` = '" . $db->quote($userData['id']) . "', `name` = '" . $db->quote($userData['name']) . "',`access_token` = '" . $db->quote($token) . "',`alive` ='Y'";
```

And on the update statement in the same place.

Comment: Good eye, sadly still no row in the database

Answer (score 0):

Ok I am going to tell you one thing, please use placeholders. I have also been through the same problem which you are in right now. mysql_ functions are deprecated and hence developers have to use PDO or mysqli_ functions.

Please check the code and see if it works

```
<?php
    if($userData) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE user_id = :user_id";
        $result = $db->prepare($query);
        $result->execute(array(':user_id' => $userData['id']));
        if ($result) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                if ($result->rowCount > 1) {
                $sql = "DELETE FROM tokens WHERE `user_id` = :user_id AND `id` != :id";
                $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->execute(array(':user_id' => $userData['id'], ':id' => $row['id']));
            }
        }

        if(!$row) {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO  tokens SET `user_id` = :user_id, `name` = :name,`access_token` = :access_token ,`alive` ='Y'";
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute(array(':user_id' => $userData['id'], ':name' => $userData['name'], ':access_token' => $token));
        } else {
            $sql = "UPDATE tokens SET `access_token` = :access_token WHERE `id` = :id";
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute(array(':access_token' => $token, ':id' => $row['id']));
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Rahul, I have no idea, but that still doesn't seem to be submitting!?